# Toggling menu makes nav text go down

Tags: css

Whenever I close my menu, the nav text goes under and it adds margin to nav items. How can I keep the text in one place without moving?
Am I missing some css class?

Here is jsfiddle with preview:

```js
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.menuClose');
const menu = document.querySelector('.box1');
const pushd = document.querySelector('.pusher');
const logoText = document.querySelector('.logo-text');
const text = document.querySelectorAll('.span-text');

const showMenu = (toggleId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId);
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      menu.classList.toggle('show');
      pushd.classList.toggle('show1');
    }) 
}

showMenu('menuClose', 'box1');
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 240px;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;

}

.show {
  width: calc(240px - 170px);
}

.show1 {
  margin-left: 70px !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;

}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.pusher {
  margin-left: 240px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
<div class="pusher"></div>
<div class="box1" id="box1">
    <div class="logo">
        <h4 class="logo-text">Logo</h4>
        <i class='bx bx-menu-alt-right' id='menuClose' class='menuClose'></i>
    </div>
    
    <ul>

        <li class="nav__item">
            <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon' ></i>
            <span class="span-text">Home page</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon' ></i>
            <span class="span-text">Home page</span>
        </li>

        <li class="nav__item">
            <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon' ></i>
            <span class="span-text">Home page</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <p>dadaw</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Original JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dawid1798/abfsr9to/3/

Comment: Your code is not adding a margin, it's caused by the overflow on the text, where the text in the navigation is being wrapped. which gives the illusion of a margin

Comment: You need to hide all instances of span-text, on close and show on menu opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is getting wrapped into the second and/or third-line because when the `box` element is collapsing the width of the text holder `span` is reducing.

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.nav__item` in CSS

By adding this you are forcing the text not to wrap even if the minimum width of space required to show the text in a single line is not available.

Comment: well, I guess you could do this if you're feeling lazy and can't be bothered to hide the .span-text instance.

Comment: @waheedrahman .. hiding span text will take precise timing went to hide and when to show. The hassle of this is easily overcome by using CSS.